# Windbag vs. demagogue

Tags: differences

[I was told](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7389) that a person who delivers long speeches but no information is called a *windbag*. A demagogue is a political leader who represents popular tendencies (it has a negative color likewise we do not have the democracy and true democracy is bad). Meantime, a prominent writer and theorist of logical debate, [Paul Graham says](http://www.paulgraham.com/disagree.html)

> An eloquent speaker or writer can give the impression of vanquishing
>   an opponent merely by using forceful words. In fact that is probably
>   the defining quality of a *demagogue*.

It seems to me that he meant to say *windbag* here. I am asking because I use the Greek work demagogue for windbag. Might be the demagogue and *windbag* are just synonyms (and we must blame the vocabulary compilers that they do not include windbaning notion into the *demagogue* article)?

Comment: Substituting ‘windbag’ in that quote would make it utterly meaningless. A windbag is someone who, when they're talking, sound like nothing more than the wind blowing in a bag: empty air. There's nothing there. Demagoguery, on the other hand, is a rhetorical device that bases itself entirely on the ‘popular pathos’, as it were, but certainly does not sound empty like wind bowing in a bag. The two are _very_ different concepts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [windbag](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/windbag) may just go on and on to no purpose.
A [demagogue](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/demagogue) tries to gain support by long-winded appeals to emotion, catchphrases, demonizing, and the like. If you don't buy into a demagogue's [shtick](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shtick), he may seem a windbag to you, but not to others.

Comment: As Janus Bahs Jacquet points out above, the two words are not interchangeable. One refers to a way of speaking, the other is about the use of rhetorical argument to gain power. Not every demagogue is like Hitler, and does not necessarily use speeches to whip up popular hysteria in the way that he did. But all demagogues appeal to popular prejudice in some way. An earlier German Chancellor, namely Bismarck won support through his foreign wars, and during the 'kulturkampf' the depiction of Socialists and Roman Catholics as 'reichsfiendes' (enemies of the state).